turtlebot3 gazebo bad lidar camera alignment
I'm running on ROS Noetic.
I'm having problems with camera lidar alignment in gazebo which should have been perfect.

I used the waffle_pi and made 2 adjustments:
  <xacro:include filename="$(find ouster_description)/urdf/OS1-64.urdf.xacro"/>
  <xacro:OS1-64>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.4" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </xacro:OS1-64>

on top of turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf.xacro
and adding to turtlebot3_world.launch:
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="waffle_state_publisher"/>

I tried the same thing for VLP-16 and same results. I got my ouster from https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/ouster_description and velodyne from velodyne_simulator via sudo apt install.
